# references in visual c#

Tags: c#

I would like to select an image reference from a string. This looks quite simple but I am new to c#.

My code at the moment looks like:

```
switch (stringCharacterName1)
    {
        case "Paul": picCharacter1.Image = WindowsApplication.Properties.Resources.Paul; break;
        case "Bob": picCharacter1.Image = WindowsApplication.Properties.Resources.Bob; break;
        and so on...
    }

switch (stringCharacterName2)
    {
        case "Paul": picCharacter2.Image = WindowsApplication.Properties.Resources.Paul; break;
        case "Bob": picCharacter2.Image = WindowsApplication.Properties.Resources.Bob; break;
        and so on...
    }

    and so on...
```

I have 32 names and 8 character selection so it is quite long...

I am searching for a way to write this like:

```
picCharacter1.Image = WindowsApplication.Properties.Resources.stringCharacterName1;
picCharacter2.Image = WindowsApplication.Properties.Resources.stringCharacterName2;
```

But it doesn't work... Maybe this problem has already been solved but I don't find something similar. Thanks for help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with the following code :

```
picCharacter1.Image = (Image)Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(stringCharacterName1);
```